# Is it required to do a HTTPUrlConnection.connect() if I am already opening a connection when I create an object?

Tags: java, http, url, connection

Consider the following piece of code. Is the connection.connect redundant since I am doing a url.openConnection(). If yes, then why do we have a .connect() method? Is it for reconnecting after we close a connection?

```
URL url;
        url = new URL(
                "http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?format=json&title=1&user-agent=TwitterProject&url="
                        + someURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        String full = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            full = full + line;
        }
        jsonresponse = JSONObject.fromObject(full);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[public abstract void connect() throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29)

> Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, if
>   such a connection has not already been established. If the connect
>   method is called when the connection has already been opened
>   (indicated by the connected field having the value true), the call is
>   ignored.

In your case call is ignored.

```
 connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();// already established connection.
```